# macOS System Integrity Protection Configuration

Tags: macos, security, root, sip

I was looking to lock down the configuration on some macs, and wanted to know if there is any way to change the files and folders that SIP protects.  I know it can be disabled, and its current rules viewed, but is there any way to add your own protected directories?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to add your own protected directory to SIP:

- Boot to Recovery Mode and disable SIP
- Reboot and create a directory structure.
- Flag the whole folder or single files or folders:

  ```
  sudo chflags restricted /example
  sudo chflags restricted /example/example.app
  sudo chflags restricted /example/subdir/file
  ```

  or a folder hierarchy:

  ```
  sudo chflags -R restricted /example
  ```

  If you want to exclude a subdir after using the -R option you have to remove the restricted flag there:

  ```
  sudo chflags norestricted /example/subdir
  ```
- Boot to Recovery Mode and enable SIP

Now the folders *example*, *example.app* and the file */example/subdir/file* are protected. You still can add or remove files to/from */example/subdir*.

---

The *restricted* flag has no effect if SIP is disabled - the usual POSIX/ACLs permissions apply. With SIP enabled the files/folders are protected.

---

It is also possible to add, remove or change SIP-protected files and directories via an installer package which is signed by Apple’s own certificate authority. Since a normal user /customer usually doesn't have access to this certificate authority, this possibility is eliminated.

---

An earlier version of this answer asserted that it is required to modify the file /System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf and add something like:

```
                                /example
                                /example/example.app
*                               /example/subdir
                                /example/subdir/file
```

**This is wrong! Simply flagging a file or folder as *restricted* is sufficient to protect it.**

Comment: Please clarify: Why is it "wrong", is it unnecessary, doesn't work, overreaching, bad practice…

Answer (score 1):

<s>As far as I know, there is no way to modify which directories SIP protects; SIP is either [on or off](https://ss64.com/osx/csrutil.html). Apple appears [to make no mention to such an ability in their developer documents either.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)</s>

Disregard this, @kanomath has a better answer. The latter part of my answer still stands to a limited degree.

If you want to lock down configuration files, modify the filesystem permissions either [through the Finder GUI](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21997) or the command line utility `chown`.

Comment: Fair enough, edited to refer to your answer.